# Angular: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: angular, unexpected-token

My import don work correctly. I am a novice in angular.

My program is easy. I have 2 files:

customer.ts

```
class Person {
  constructor(protected name: string, private age: number) {}

  welcome(): string {
    return `Witaj ${this.name}, czy masz ${this.age} lat?`;
  }
}


export class Customer extends Person {
  constructor(name: string, age: number, private advisor: string) {
    super(name, age);
  }

  welcome(): string{
    return `Siema ${this.name}`;
  }
}
```

example.ts

```
import {Customer} from "./customer";
let jan = new Customer("Jan", 44, "Agata");
console.log(jan);
```

My command is: ts-node sandbox/example.ts
All files are in sandbox folder.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
```

Comment: a stackblitz which recreates this issue will help get you an answer here

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your ts-node version.

Because I was unable to recreate the issue.

node: 9.8.0

npm: 6.4.1

ts-node: 7.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Hey check it in here : (on the console)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-4xqc14?file=index.ts

Hope this helps!